# FactoryGirl: create_list from a previous create_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm pretty new using FG and I'm trying to create several objects from a previous "create_list" call. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
 let(:questions) { FactoryGirl.create_list :question, 5 }
 let(:answers)   { questions.map do |q|
                     FactoryGirl.create :answer, question: q
                   end
                 }
```

Looks smelly to me.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your data model.

Do questions require an answer?

If yes, consider [FactoryGirl associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

If not, create them in your tests if and when you need them as you will likely need to test cases where questions do not have answers.

Answer (score 1):

All of the FactoryGirl builder methods support providing a block which is yielded the newly created object. Using this, you can create your records and associations in a single call.

For example,

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:question, 5) do |question|
   question.answers = FactoryGirl.build_list(:answer)
   # or...
   # question.answers.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:answer))
end
```

**Resources**

- [FactoryGirl documentation for block support](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Using_factories)